# Array only contain numbers in php

Tags: php, arrays

Hi guys i have an array

```
$a=[1,2,3,4,5,...]
```

But i want to check if any other element than number exist in array
For example

These are my arrays

```
$a=[1,2,3,4,5,a,6,b,7]
$b=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

$a has numbers and variables

$b has numbers only

So my output is

check($a) should be false

check($b) should be true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) and simple [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) will be usful in this case. 
Iterate over each element of array using **foreach** and check if the element is number or not using **is_numeric()** function.

Like this,

```
function check($array) {
     foreach($array as $value) {
          if (!is_numeric($value)) {
               return false;
          } 
     }
     return true;
}
```

Just return false as soon as you hit the first non-numeric.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1):

You should use PHP is_numeric() function. Iterate over your array and apply this function to check if values are numeric . A sample for such logic from PHP documentation page is given below .

```
foreach ($tests as $element) {
    if (is_numeric($element)) {
        echo "'{$element}' is numeric", PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "'{$element}' is NOT numeric", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```